# If else not working in phpmyadmin trigger

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, triggers, phpmyadmin

So I was working with MySQL triggers in phpmyadmin. Here's my trigger for table scorm_track:

```
UPDATE userbatch 
LEFT JOIN scorm_track 
ON      
        (userbatch.user_id = scorm_track.userid)
LEFT JOIN trainingobject
ON      
        (scorm_track.tobjid = trainingobject.id)
IF scorm_track.element = 'cmi.core.lesson_status' THEN
    SET userbatch.to_completion = scorm_track.value,
        userbatch.trainingcompleted = scorm_track.timemodified;
ELSEIF scorm_track.element = 'cmi.core.score.raw' THEN
    SET userbatch.comment = scorm_track.value;
ENDIF;
WHERE (userbatch.batch_id = trainingobject.batchid) AND 
        scorm_track.id=NEW.id AND 
        scorm_track.element = 'cmi.core.lesson_status' OR scorm_track.element = 'cmi.core.score.raw'
```

But it shows the following error: "MySQL said #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax..."

This problem started occurring after I added the IF ELSE statements. It was working fine before. Can anyone suggest why this maybe occuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of wrong update syntax while joining. The `if-else` usage is wrong here. The query should be something as

```
update userbatch ub
left join scorm_track st on ub.user_id = st.userid
left join trainingobject tob on tob.id = st.tobjid
set
ub.to_completion = 
 case 
   when st.element = 'cmi.core.lesson_status' then st.value 
 end ,
ub.to_completion = 
 case when st.element = 'cmi.core.lesson_status' then st.value 
end, 
ub.trainingcompleted = 
 case when st.element = 'cmi.core.lesson_status' then st.timemodified 
end, 
ub.comment = 
case when st.element = 'cmi.core.score.raw' then st.value 
end
where 
ub.batch_id = tob.batchid
and st.id = new.id 
and ( st.element = 'cmi.core.lesson_status' or st.element = 'cmi.core.score.raw )
```

Comment: Note that a case statement will result in NULL when no ELSE is specified and none of the expressions is evaluate to true.

Comment: As pointed by Gervs, the trainingcompleted and to_completion columns are set to NULL when cmi.core.score.raw is encountered. Any other way?